# centos6 - wireshark

Tags: linux, centos, yum, wireshark

1) Is there any easy way to install wireshark-1.8.3 on centos 6 ?

I try the wget utility and i get the dependency on gtk..which inturn has dependency on glib, atk , pango and cairo..

2) Looks like my yuminstall also is broken..My yum.conf file is as follows..

```
[main]
cachedir=/var/cache/yum
keepcache=0
debuglevel=2
logfile=/var/log/yum.log
distroverpkg=redhat-release
tolerant=1
exactarch=1
obsoletes=1
gpgcheck=1
plugins=1
bugtracker_url=http://bugs.centos.org/yum5bug

# Note: yum-RHN-plugin doesn't honor this.
metadata_expire=1h

installonly_limit = 5

# PUT YOUR REPOS HERE OR IN separate files named file.repo
# in /etc/yum.repos.d
```

Comment: consider dumping with `tcpdump` and viewing the resulting `.pcap` file on another computer with wireshark

Comment: Do you have graphical access?

Answer (score 0):

Wireshark is a graphical application, so, do you have Xserver running (kde/gnome etc etc)? If only have shell access, then you can't use wireshark. You should use tcpdump as suggested by fuero.

If you have graphical access to CentOS box. I just tested on my CentOS box, I did 'yum search wireshark' and it found it. I don't have any problems installing it.

So, why do want to use wireshark? Is there anything you're looking for?